# Is there a setup where I can leave the water on all summer?

Tags: plumbing, gardening

I have an elderly person that is no longer able to walk the land to reach the faucet.  It's about 20' between the safe patio and the faucet.  She needs to turn on the faucet in order to hand water the garden (a task she enjoys so not thinking of using drip system).   My idea is to run a hose to the patio.  Then put a shut off valve there.  This means the hose and other equipment will need to be able to handle constant pressure for 3 months at a time in Texas.

Is there a hose and shut off that can handle this job?  My initial thought is a [heavy duty hose](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Neverkink-5-8-in-Dia-x-25-ft-Heavy-Duty-Water-Hose-8605-25/100661323) and a [brass shut off coupling](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Orbit-3-4-in-Threaded-Brass-Shut-Off-Coupling-27933/100659291).

Comment: Looks like it would work. If she has trouble bending over to operate the valve, one can make a 3 ft long "wrench" out of Sch 40  PVC tubing to turn the handle from waist height.

Comment: The only problem I see is that if the hose lays in direct sun it may burst.  Two things happen the hose itself gets softer and the pressure increases as the water temperature rises in a closed off hose.  Probably wouldn’t burst a new hose for awhile, but watch it for wear.  Another idea is [Orbits Bluetooth faucet timer](https://www.orbitonline.com/products/hose-watering/timers/hose-faucet-timers/smart-timers/b-hyve-smart-hose-faucet-valve-2278) which would allow remotely turning the faucet on and off, if the elderly person can handle a simple smartphone app, that might be a challenge too tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really not much that can fail in a setup like that if you use quality components. A hose bib on a post or standpipe used to be a common sight in gardens before underground irrigation became so common.

[image]

Even with old rubber hoses disaster rarely struck. Modern reinforced hoses make failure a very remote possibility that shouldn't dissuade you from following your plan.

Run a good hose from the faucet and install whatever valve or hose bib that suits the good lady's needs.

Comment: I agree + . prior to installing underground plumbing to outside paddocks we fed all 4 with hoses 200' at first set and almost 400 to the second set this worked great in the summer but we had several ballvalves plastic and brass freeze and crack never lost a hose in winter and no problems in the summer.

Answer (score 1):

Even inside the house, the recommendation is to replace washing machine water hoses every five years.  Outside, the hose is exposed to a lot of UV light, which breaks down many synthetic materials, and it gets hot in the summer, which softens the hose and increases the pressure.  If the water remains turned on, the hose is continuously under pressure.

A good hose should last a number of years outside, but the service life will be shorter than a hose inside under the same continuous pressure.  Many people do get away with using a garden hose like this for a very long time, just like many people get away with never changing their washing machine hoses.  But failures do happen, and when they do, the hose tends to be the least expensive part of the damage.

If you only need it to last a few years, use a garden hose and you should be fine.  But if this is something that will be permanent, and it is between two fixed locations, and especially if it will usually be unattended so failure could go a long time without being noticed, use plastic pipe intended for the purpose.  It will be a little more work, but then you don't have to worry about failures.